# SQL - Finding sequence of events

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need some help identifying a sequence of events in SQL Server 08 R2.
This is the sample data:

```
    ID | SampleTime | SampleValue | CycleNum
    1  | 07:00:00   | 10          |
    2  | 07:02:00   | 10          |
    3  | 07:05:00   | 10          |
    4  | 07:12:00   | 20          |
    5  | 07:15:00   | 10          |
    6  | 07:22:00   | 10          |
    7  | 07:23:00   | 20          |
    8  | 07:30:00   | 20          |
    9  | 07:31:00   | 10          |
```

I have used the following as a guide, [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115717/identify-sequence-of-events-based-on-certain-rules)
, but it doesn't give the required output

The rules are:

- A cycle starts at 10 and finishes at 20
- There can be multiple 10s before a 20, and multiple 20s before the next 10
- A cycle will always start at the first 10, and finish on the last 20 before the next 10.

Example Output

```
    ID | SampleTime | SampleValue | CycleNum
    1  | 07:00:00   | 10          |  1
    2  | 07:02:00   | 10          |  1
    3  | 07:05:00   | 10          |  1
    4  | 07:12:00   | 20          |  1
    5  | 07:15:00   | 10          |  2
    6  | 07:22:00   | 10          |  2
    7  | 07:23:00   | 20          |  2
    8  | 07:30:00   | 20          |  2
    9  | 07:31:00   | 10          |  3
```

Test Table

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (ID INT IDENTITY, SampleTime DATETIME, SampleValue INT, CycleNum INT)
INSERT INTO myTable (SampleTime, SampleValue)
VALUES ('07:00:00',10),
       ('07:02:00',10),
       ('07:05:00',10),
       ('07:12:00',20),
       ('07:15:00',10),
       ('07:22:00',10),
       ('07:23:00',20),
       ('07:30:00',20),
       ('07:31:00',10)
```

Comment: Is the `ID` column guaranteed to be contiguous?

Comment: Yes - does using IDENTITY for the table design guarantee this?

Comment: Using IDENTITY doesn't guarantee contiguous values. See [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL) IDENTITY (Property)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this... this will give the mapping of ID and CYCLENUM

```
WITH EVE_DATA AS (
  SELECT ID
    , SAMPLETIME
    , SAMPLEVALUE
    , CASE 
        WHEN (SAMPLEVALUE - lag(SAMPLEVALUE, 1, 0) over (order by SAMPLETIME ASC)) = -10
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS START_IND
  FROM
  MY_TABLE
)
SELECT T1.id
  , SUM(T2.START_IND) + 1 AS CycleNum 
FROM EVE_DATA T1
  JOIN EVE_DATA T2
    ON T1.ID >= T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.ID
ORDER BY T1.ID;
```

Comment: You can change the unsupported `lag` expression to `(select samplevalue from mytable m where m.id = (mytable.id - 1))`. The expression `mytable.id - 1` is not robust, because there could be gaps in the sequence. But it's sufficient to show the way.